# Comparing value of 2 columns, finding first match to use in 3rd column

Tags: excel, vba

So my data looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, first values line up, and so 429.jpg would go in middle column. However sometimes the values don't line up, so I'm looking for a way to compare values and find the first match so we can use in middle column. Column A is product name, C is image name.

**EDIT:** So the only tricky thing is a lot of the image names have 000s in front of the sku. but the good news is the skus have no leading 0. So I'm trying to figure out how to remove the leading 0, and then match after that.

I have tried this so far (someone helped me come up with it, however it's not working):

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, arr(), r As Long, c As Long
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    arr = ws.Range("A2:C" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    
    On Error Resume Next
    
    For r = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
        
        For c = LBound(arr, 1) To UBound(arr, 1)
            
            ' Having trouble with this piece ..
            
            Select Case True
                    
                Case Right$(arr(c, 3), 9) = "-ROOM.jpg" And Left$(arr(c, 3), Len(arr(c, 3)) - 9) = arr(r, 1)
                    arr(r, 2) = arr(c, 3)
                    Exit For
                Case Right$(arr(c, 3), 6) = "-5.jpg" And Left$(arr(c, 3), Len(arr(c, 3)) - 6) = arr(r, 1)
                    arr(r, 2) = arr(c, 3)
                    Exit For
                Case Right$(arr(c, 3), 6) = "-6.jpg" And Left$(arr(c, 3), Len(arr(c, 3)) - 6) = arr(r, 1)
                    arr(r, 2) = arr(c, 3)
                    Exit For
                    
            End Select
            
        Next
        
    Next
    
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    ws.Range("A2").Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)) = arr
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you elaborate how you identify a "match"? Would `701.jpg` be a match for `701`? Would  `00701.jpg` be a match? What is it about the `Room` and `-5` in the file names? Are the SKUs always be numeric?

Comment: Hi, sorry. so the only tricky thing is a lot of the image names have 000s in front of the sku. but the good news is the skus have no leading 0. So I'm trying to figure out how to remove the leading 0, and then match after that.

Comment: Yes, 00701.jpg would be a match.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand, the image name may contain leading zeros, then the SKU-number, then maybe kind of suffix (`-ROOM` or `-5`), following by file file extension (`.jpg`).

So the first task is to figure out the SKU from the file name, and that is extremely simple: Just use the `Val` function that will convert a String into a number. The function stops at the first non-digit character, so `0000123.jpg` will return the number `123`. Put this into a small function (using a function has the advantage that if you one day find that the logic no longer fits, you just have to rewrite the function, but the rest of the code remains untouched):

```
Function getSKUFromFilename(filename As String) As Long
    getSKUFromFilename = Val(filename)
End Function
```

What you do in your code is looping over all your lines of data in a nested loop. Having lots of data, this would result in a lot of work, for 1000 rows you would have 1000*1000 iterations.

I suggest to use a different attempt: Loop once over your data and build a Dictionary, with the extracted SKUs as key and the filenames as value.
With that dictionary, loop over the SKUs of your sheet, look if you have an entry in the dictionary and if yes, write the filename into the column B:

```
Sub FillImageNames()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, imageArr()
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    imageArr = ws.Range("C2:C" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row)
    
    ' (1) Fill Dictionary
    Dim d As New Dictionary
    Dim row As Long
    For row = 1 To UBound(imageArr, 1)
        Dim filename As String, sku As Long
        filename = Trim(imageArr(row, 1))
        If filename <> "" Then
            sku = getSKUFromFilename(filename)
            d(sku) = filename
        End If
    Next
    
    ' (2) Fill sheet
    Dim lastRow as Long
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
    For row = 2 To lastRow
        sku = Val(ws.Cells(row, 1))
        If d.Exists(sku) Then
            ws.Cells(row + 1, 2) = d(sku)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Note that you need to add a reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime.

Comment: So I noticed it stops when column A runs out of values. Is there a way to keep it iterating over the reamining 6k lines in column C to match the rest?

Comment: The dictionary is brilliant, it works great! Just have the problem above. If you can address that I will accept ASAP.

Comment: The script stops running at row 133, for whatever reason. Before that it matches most of them perfectly.

Comment: I thought your part filling the array was already working. I slightly changed the code. Try it - and if it is not processing all your data, use the debugger to check why it fails.

Comment: Hmm, appears to be syntax errror on line `sku = Val(ws.Cells(row, 1)` -- its highlihgted in red in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Syntax error was just a missing parenthesis on `Val()` method. However now I'm getting a **Type Mismatch Error**? It's for line `For row = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)`

Comment: I changed the name of the variable (from `arr`  to `imageArr`) but forgot to change that line. My fault - edited the code here without checking it. Corrected. The fact that you got a `Type mismatch` shows me that you don't use `Option Explicit` - you should **always** use it.

Comment: I'm getting a strange errror now: Ambiguous name detected? It's talking about the `getSkuFromFileName()` method.

Comment: So weird because intiially it worked perfectly until row 133. Now it just won't work with the **ambiguous error**

Comment: You have somewhere an extra declaration of something named `getSkuFromFileName` - maybe you copied the function twice, or you dim a variable with that name - something like that. Search your code for that name (select "Current Project" in the Find Dialog) and see if you can find it.

Comment: Ok I found and removed that, however the function is not doing anything when I click "Run". Any idea why that may be? Thank you for your help thus far!

Comment: I have a lot of ideas what might fail. I would suggest you use the debugger and step thru the code to check why it fails. Check the number of rows written into the dictionary. Check if `lastRow` is correct. Check if the SKUs are found in the dictionary. And so on. Learning to debug your code is essential for programming,